# Hinge pin problem in installation

Tags: hinges, installation

First of all, I'm fully aware that, this is a very simple question. but I can't find the solution.

I want to make the foldable leg for a table like this : 
[image]
so I cut top and bottom of each leg 10 degrees. and installed the hinges  :
[image]
The problem is "pin part" when it folds [image], so I cant attach the leg surface to the table top sheet. 
[image]

**EDIT :**
According to [Fred_dot_u](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/a/7474/2913) answer :

I bought the hinge that you've mentioned from the local store, The point is that hinge does not fold in the direction that I want or I'm installing that in the wrong way? 
[image]
[image]

Comment: The section of a hinge that the pin passes through is called the knuckle. Using the first hinge you pictured all you need to do is mount it a little away from the ends and the knuckle won't project above the legs when they're opened up. In case you don't know you will likely have to install a chain or length of cord to keep the legs from trying to open up wider than you want them to.

Answer (score 2):

You are seeking what is called a flush two-pin hinge:

[https://www.amazon.com/Whitecap-Flush-Mount-2-Pin-Hinge/dp/B004MDY00W](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004MDY00W)

[image: flush two pin hinge]

The image shows one of many options and of many designs. Some are engineered to mount on a surface, but even that isn't a requirement. Some "ordinary" hinges will have flush pin configuration without having two pins.

The design in the image may require careful spacing in order to accomplish a flat surface and the legs may not necessarily be in contact. I don't think that's an issue in your design.

Comment: thank you for your reply, should I add mortise the legs for hinges ?!

Comment: Unless you are concerned with the appearance of the underside of the legs, I don't know that it's worth the extra labor.

Comment: Please check the question again ,

Comment: I don't have a photo, as the mechanism in which I used the hinge is no longer in my possession, but it would appear that there may be different hinges with different hinging action. The hinge in your photos have some geometry that prevents folding in the other direction, while the one I used (years ago) did not have that restriction.

Comment: @Mironline, I'm not familiar with these hinges but if you look at the pics of other hinges of this type on Amazon, under **Customers who viewed this item also viewed** it would appear these hinges always fold upwards only. [Example](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61pJJOOQnoL._SL1000_.jpg). And [here](http://assets.seattlepub.com/SuperContainer/RawData/Sea-Dog/LineArt/2586?width=380&height=380) is the same hinge on another site.